# If (picturebox1.location =

Tags: c#

I'm just learning C# and have a question.

i need something like this.

```
if (pictureBox1.Location = 177, 523)
{
....
}
```

how can i do this?

Comment: Not sure myself as I don't use the drawing libraries, but have you tried if (pictureBox1.Location == new Point( 177, 523))?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Location property is of type Point.  You'll need

```
if (pictureBox1.Location == new Point(177, 523)) { ... }
```

or

```
if (pictureBox1.Left == 177 && pictureBox1.Top == 523) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `picturebox1.Left` and `picturebox1.Top` properties rather than the `.Location`.